# UserControl is not Resizing in Panel

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-designer

I'm having a problem using user controls with panels. When I load user control into the panel with the code:

```
 panel3.Controls.Add(new userControl1());
```

it loads with the size of my initial usercontrol1 size. Actually, I have already made my form to maximize with this code.

```
 this.MaximizedBounds = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea;
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

I also tried all the solutions I was able to find.
1- I tried to `Dock` `Fill` with the panel, user control, Anchoring to all sides.
2- Also did `AutoSize = True` for user control and panel.
Nothing works at this point.

Actually, when I first time did load user control into the panel it loaded okay in my original project. then I don't know what happened. The image uploaded below is captured from the scratch new project. So, be sure it's not a problem with my original project either.

[Sample Problem Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IHBe.png)

Answer (score 0):

I Think you're looking for this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10871592/16165399

In your UserControl : `this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).